# Customizing 'Facebook Share' Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, api, facebook-sharer

I am editing this question so that it makes more sense than what I originally wrote.

I am implementing the code below in order to add a Facebook "Share" button to my website. My problem is that this script calls for actual values for 'link', 'picture', 'name', 'caption', and 'description' directly in the script.

How can I change this code so that it pulls this information from my website automatically. For example, I need it to pull the URL from the current and assign it to 'link'. Another example: instead of providing the URL for the picture, I want to point the code to a certain class.

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

This is from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` will only return the path portion of a URL, you also need to add your domain also. `window.location.href` will return this. Pretty easy to change your code to do this:

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: window.location.href,
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks! what is the best way to implement this into the code? I want to assign window.location.href to the "link" attribute correctly.

Comment: Have added to my answer. Remember you'll also need to swap out the App ID for your own app's ID.

Comment: thanks! that correction helped. I was able to figure out how to assign the object parameters and things worked correctly.